# SPARQL - What does a single colon do in a prefix?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I've often seen a SPARQL query starting with this prefix:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
```

But what exactly does it mean to use only a colon ":" in a prefix? I usually know it as putting another abbreviation in front of it. Like for example here:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
```

Is there a reason to write it this way, and if so, what is the function of the prefix?
I would imagine that this would cover any other abbreviations that were not assigned. But unfortunately I've not found anything specific about this on the Internet

Comment: a single colon is also just a prefix name, it's just the empty string

Comment: @UninformedUser Ah ok that makes sense. Could you then use ":prefix" instead of "dbr:prefix" in a query, for example?

Comment: well, you mean the correct thing, but the prefix **is** `:` as is `dbr` is a prefix, so it would be `:some` yes. And yes, you can use `:` instead of `dbr:` - it's just that in a query with different entities from different vocabularies sometimes it helps to read `dbr`. In the end a matter of taste I'd say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no special functionality involved. It’s a regular prefix label, which happens to be empty.

[SPARQL: Prefixed Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#prefNames) (bold emphasis mine):

> The `PREFIX` keyword associates a prefix label with an IRI. A prefixed name is a prefix label and a local part, separated by a colon "`:`". A prefixed name is mapped to an IRI by concatenating the IRI associated with the prefix and the local part. The prefix label or the local part **may be empty**.

So these three snippets are equivalent:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?person a <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .
}
```

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?person a foaf:Person .
}
```

```
PREFIX : <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?person a :Person .
}
```

Using an empty prefix label in SPARQL queries might make sense if all, or almost all, IRIs come from the same ontology, because the query might become more readable then.